# I need to build a java application which would keep asking for data on a url every 10 secs

Tags: java, cakephp

At first I thought this is a programming issue as I am creating connections every 10 seconds.Which might get into creating connections and not properly closing it.But as  suggested its not programming but an implementation/design issue.

I need to check for any new resource available every 5 or 10 seconds ex: testign.com/list_items.
The webservices are developed using cakephp.

If any resource available I will be processing it.
Can anyone help/guide me to connect to url and poll the new resource every 10 secs.

Every 10 secs doing the below code gives a connection refused or connection timed out exception after 20 loops and also after the exception starts hitting in, the url cannot be loaded on the browser.

```
oracleIncoming = new URL("http://calvins.restasy.com/bills/list_current/Kitchen");
    inputStreamReaderList = new InputStreamReader(oracleIncoming.openStream());

    //= new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream());
    for (int j = 0; j < 10;) {
        URLReader.inputStreamReaderList.close();
        inputStreamReaderList = new InputStreamReader(oracleIncoming.openStream());




        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(URLReader.inputStreamReaderList);

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        URLReader.storeInput = URLReader.storeInput + inputLine;
    }
    in.close();

        URLReader.storeInput = "";
        //send response with bill no
        if (URLReader.sendBillNo == true) {
            URLReader.sendBillNo = false;

            oracle = new URL("http://calvins.restasy.com/bills/successfully_generated/" +billNo+"/"+"Kitchen");
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream());
             try {

                BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);


                String inputLine2;
                while ((inputLine2 = in2.readLine()) != null) {
                    urlBillData2 = urlBillData2 + inputLine2;
                }
                in.close();
                inputStreamReader.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
            System.out.println("Successfully Printed Order " + billNo);
            //System.out.println("http://calvins.restasy.com/bills/successfully_generated/" +billNo);
        }
        Thread.sleep(10000);
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
    callWeb();
}
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:163)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:394)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:529)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:233)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:306)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:323)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:970)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:911)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:836)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1172)
at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
at printerapp.URLReader.callWeb(URLReader.java:122)
at printerapp.URLReader.main(URLReader.java:71)
```

As HotLicks suggested to respond from web-service only after any resource is available, the php timeout for an execution is 30 seconds.
How to keep a request alive for more than this time.Increasing PHP execution time limit would be a security issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not a very specific question.

Comment: @JesseJ What details do I need to provide.I have added more details does it help?

Comment: I had asked this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16303252/getting-connection-timed-out-or-refused-after-few-loops?noredirect=1#comment23341037_16303252 but dint get any answers.So thought I am not doing the whole thing properly.

Comment: I think you are not experiencing a programming problem but a reaction of the server against excessive scraping.

Comment: @luksch okay so how can I actually achieve the intended task of polling for new resources via api

Comment: @AvinashShetty Asking a new question is not the best way to go about getting an answer. In most cases editing the original question with updated, relevant information will bump it to the main page so new eyes can seee it. In this case, this question is poor quality, whereas your other question has code, and exception information.

Comment: @Avinash Shetty does the server owner approve of this? if so, you can ask. If not, you may wander into the dark land of faking user agents, using proxies and such...

Comment: @RobertH Okay.That makes sense.Will update the old question.

Comment: @luksch I have a godaddy shared hosting to test this application.Our team only has developed the api's so doen it means server owner approves ?

Comment: In general, you should not be polling a web site every 5 seconds.  Where near instantaneous response is needed the web site should provide a mechanism where you can issue a `get` and the server will not respond until there is data available (though there should generally be a timeout after several minutes).

Comment: @HotLicks okay so that way we can get resource when its created.But wont the java `openstream()` which issues a `get` has a time out for waiting for a response.

Comment: Yes, there will be a timeout, which you'd normally set on the order of 5-10 minutes, at which time you'd reissue the get.

Comment: I have added few more details to question.Even it is closed I am trying to improve the question instead of creating new one as @RobertH told.Hope I am on right track.

Comment: @HotLicks if you can put your comment in anasswer I can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you should not be polling a web site every 5 seconds. Where near instantaneous response is needed the web site should provide a mechanism where you can issue a get and the server will not respond until there is data available (though there should generally be a timeout after several minutes).

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true) {
    dataIncoming = new URL("http://xyz.com/bills/list_current/Kitchen");
    inputStreamReaderList = new InputStreamReader(dataIncoming.openStream());

    //Your code

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        //Thread.sleep() can throw an exception if you
        //notify the thread from another thread
    }
}
```